# Creating file that uses UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to create a file and encode its content in the **UTF-8** format using C. I have tried several things and looked around but I can not seem to find a solution to the problem.

This is the code I am currently trying (**u8_wc_tout8** function taken from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html)):

```
int u8_wc_toutf8(char *dest, u_int32_t ch)
{
    if (ch < 0x80) {
        dest[0] = (char)ch;
        return 1;
    }
    if (ch < 0x800) {
        dest[0] = (ch>>6) | 0xC0;
        dest[1] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 2;
    }
    if (ch < 0x10000) {
        dest[0] = (ch>>12) | 0xE0;
        dest[1] = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[2] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 3;
    }
    if (ch < 0x110000) {
        dest[0] = (ch>>18) | 0xF0;
        dest[1] = ((ch>>12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[2] = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[3] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main ()
{

    printf(setlocale(LC_ALL, "")); //Prints C.UTF-8

    FILE * fout;
    fout=fopen("out.txt","w");

    u_int32_t c = 'Å';
    char convertedChar[6];
    int cNum = u8_wc_toutf8(convertedChar, c);

    printf(convertedChar); //Prints ?
    fprintf(fout, convertedChar); 
    fclose(fout);

    printf("\nFile has been created...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this from the command prompt in Windows it prints `?` and when I open the file created I get some weird characters. If I check the encoding in Firefox on the file it says:

> "windows-1252"

Are there any better ways to check the encoding of the file?

Any tips to point me in the right direction would be really nice, it feels like this should not be that hard to do.

Comment: c library has the multibyte char type wchar and associated functions for handling utf and other multibyte charactersets. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/wchar.h

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `convertedChar`. Thus that pointer points to undefined memory location and you get *undefined behaviour* (= anything can happen). Declare `convertedChar` as an array instead of a pointer: `char convertedChar[MAX_UTF8_CHAR_LENGTH];`

Comment: @Kai Ikratsch When I switched to the widechar it correctly identified it in nodepad++ but still not working in Firefox for some reason.

Allocating the memory did sadly not help.

Comment: @KaiIskratsch `wchar_t` is not very good at representing Unicode. On some implementations the type is only 16-bit  wide, which is not enough for complete Unicode range.

Comment: @asiew Open the file in the hex editor instead, and check that bytes match the expected values. It's not unheard of that editors detect encoding incorrectly, so first make sure that the file actually has correct data.

Comment: `wchar_t` is a type to handle a wide char, not an `unicode char`. You need *32 bits* to handle an unicode char (i.e. an unicode character id). So keep the `u_int32_t`. And if this program works, wether with `wchar_t` or `u_int32_t`, it's only by chance. But it's a buggy program because your `convertedChar` was never initialized, so it points to an undefined location.

Comment: @user694733 I got the correct values in the hexa editor using the widechar library and writing a "wide string" to a file. Did not get the correct values with the method i first tried (memory is allocated for the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allocate the memory for `convertedChar` and set `c` to 197, which is the unicode char id of the angstrom character (Å). Then you can now encode this character in utf-8 or anything else if you want:

```
int main ()
{
    FILE * fout;
    fout=fopen("out.txt","wb");

    u_int32_t c = 197; // Or 0xC5
    char convertedChar[4];
    int cNum = u8_wc_toutf8(convertedChar, c);

    fwrite(convertedChar, sizeof(char), cNum, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    printf("\nFile has been created...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And in the case, for example, that your locale uses UTF-8 encoding, then you can use this to print the character on your console:

```
wchar_t wc;
mbtowc(&wc, convertedChar, sizeof(wchar_t));
putwc(wc, stdout);
```

Comment: Using numeric codepoint is good idea, because then source file encoding won't be an issue. However, I don't know where you got the `212` from (U+00D4 is Ô). Å is supposed to be U+00C5.

Comment: I can't be bothered write my own answer for this: You must also replace the `fprintf` with something better, because 1. it uses buffer as a format string, and 2. that string is not null terminated.

Comment: Indeed, you should not use fprintf. You want to write `cNum` characters from the `convertedChar` buffer. This can be done either with `fwrite` (write n chars) or a loop with fputc (write 1 char), but don't use `fprintf` for that.

Comment: I suggest you to open a new discussion and post a code with your" block of text".

Comment: What is an "unknown block of text" ? That `u8_wc_toutf8` function converts **one** unicode character id (`ch` - always 4 bytes) into **its UTF-8 encoding** (`convertedChar`). If you want to convert an *Unicode string* (i.e. an *array* of unicode character id = an array of *32 bits* integers), wether you call `u8_wc_toutf8` inside a loop, or simply call `u8_toutf8`.